# Field Named InternalKey is not saving through EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have column `InternalKey` in my database table. When I do update, all columns get updated except the column `InternalKey`.

Here is my code - is it a keyword?

```
vmdpkeys.LastOperationBy = user.Id;
vmdpkeys.LastOperationOn = DateTime.Now;                       

var _mapeddpkeys = _mapper.Map<SysDefaultPostingKeys>(vmdpkeys);

_mapeddpkeys.InternalKey = vmdpkeys.DefaultPostingKey.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
_defaultpostingkeysrepository.Update(_mapeddpkeys);
```

Comment: 1) What is `_defaultpostingkeysrepository.Update`? Usually people during generic repository implementation breaks normal EF Core update flow. 2) What is napping for your object? Does `InternalKey` is Primary Key?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Migration files and ModelSnapShot file and see if the IntrernalKey has been successfully added in your DB.